# Syntax error in Celsius-to-Fahrenheit converter program

Tags: java

I have to allow the user to choose which conversion to do, and what degree to start at, then print the conversion starting at that degree up to the next 9 (10 conversions). And I have to write this using a callback function. Also there is a menu in the beginning. I have an "else without if" at line  . Also my callback function is not calculating numbers correctly.  How do I resolve this error and fix my callback function?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FahrToCel {

    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double choice = 0;
        double fahrenheit = 0;
        double celsius = 0;
        double answer = 0;


        //print the welcome message and the menu options for the user
        System.out.printf("Welcome to Candace's Fahrenheit and Celsius "
            + "convertor. ");
        System.out.printf("Please choose one of the following options: \n"
            + " Press 0 to exit \n Press 1 to to convert to Celsius \n"
            + " Press 2 to convert to Fahrenheit >  ");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        //print what happens when the user hits a button
        if (choice == 0){ 
            // the user is going to exit the game
            System.out.printf("Well hopefully you can play again soon! :) ");
        } else {
            //perform code for the operation
            for ( double i = fahrenheit; i >-100; i-=10 ){
                if (choice == 1) { 
                    // it will convert from fahrenheit to celsius
                    System.out.printf("Please pick a number in Fahrenheit: > ");
                    fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
                    celsius = FahrToCel();
                    System.out.printf("%f ", i);
                }
            }
            for ( double i = celsius; i >-10; i-=10 ){
                if (choice == 2){ 
                    // it will convert from celsius to fahrenheit
                    System.out.printf("Please pick a number in celsius: > ");
                    celsius = input.nextDouble();
                    fahrenheit = CelToFahr();
                    System.out.printf("%f ", i);
                }
            } 

        } else {
            System.out.printf("I'm sorry, I did not ask you to enter that "
                + "number. ");
        }
    }

    public static double CelToFahr(){
        double celsius = 0;
        double fahrenheit = 0;
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5.0/9.0);
        return celsius;
    }

    public static double FahrToCel( ){
        //perform the conversion for fahrenheit to celsius
        double celsius = 0;
        double fahrenheit = 0;
        fahrenheit = ((9.0/5.0) + 32) * celsius;
        return fahrenheit;

    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Where it says:  else {
        System.out.printf("I'm sorry, I did not ask you to enter that "
                + "number. ");     thats where it tells me that i have a else without if error

Comment: The first else statement closes the first if. That means you second else has no if.

Comment: So how would i change that?

Comment: Cause I was trying to say if the user does not enter the numbers 0,1,or 2 then have the computer print this

Comment: I think the first else should be `else if (choice == 1)` then another `else if (choice == 2)` then just else.

Comment: i tried adding those, but its still telling me the "else without if" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a structure like this

```
if (choice == 0){
    // ...
}
else if (choice == 1) {
    for ( double i = fahrenheit; i >-100; i-=10 ){
        // ...
    }
}
else if (choice == 2) {
    for ( double i = celsius; i >-10; i-=10 ){
        // ...
    }
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

Right now you have some if statements inside of an else and your scope is getting confused. Your loops would then go inside those else if statements. Also note that you are doing the conversion many times, but printing the initial value entered each time, not the converted temperature.

Comment: But then where would my for loop go? I think I understand what your saying but im still slightly confused. So rearrange what I have around?

Comment: Good answer, @Takendarkk--considerable help without writing the code for the student. +1

Comment: oh my gosh thank you @Takendarkk that was really helpful! It works now:) Yea i think i was getting overwhelmed with all the brackets. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I helped. Just try to properly indent your code, it makes it easier to spot mistakes like these ones.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, (EDIT) ONE OF your functions is not quite right. Since they involve math, I'm offering my revisions instead of hints.

I don't know if you *want* to pass in the value you're converting from, but doing so would make it better.

You definitely don't want to set both celsius and fahrenheit to zero in both functions.

```
public static double FahrToCel(double fahrenheit ){
   double celsius;
   celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5.0/9.0);
   return celsius;
 }

public static double CelToFahr( double celsius){
    //perform the conversion for fahrenheit to celsius
    double fahrenheit;
    fahrenheit = ((9.0/5.0) ) * celsius + 32;
    return fahrenheit;
```

This would mean that inside your `for` loops, the calls to the functions would have to be something like:

```
            celsius = input.nextDouble();
            fahrenheit = CelToFahr(celsius);
```

But I'm not sure you should input the next value of celsius, if I'm reading the instructions and intent of the `for` loops correctly.

Maybe you want this instead of inputting:

```
celsius = i;
```